# Use WebDav in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, webdav, windows-explorer

I have done some research, based on the problem that my single server gives me when I try to open a document library in windows explorer from the ribbon menu item "Open in Windows Explorer".

The same problem occurs when I try to map sharepoint to a folder in windows explorer too.

The error is:

> Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer

From the net, suggestions are:

> - (Since I'm trying this operation from server itself) enable Desktop Experience
> - Install the KB907306 update.
> - Enable IIS webDav service (Some say, it's just for additional functions from the MS Whitepaper)
> - (Edit) Started webClient service

I've already done them. Nothing changed. Proper machine restart and iis too have done.

Need some serious advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if we are having exactly the same problem BUT I have had similar problem while accessing SP via Windows Explorer in Windows Server 2k8.

What I done to fix  it is following:

- Install new server feature called Desktop Experience (it comes with WebDAV redirector, which allows you to connect to WebDAV) - Note: Server will need to be restarted.
- In Services start WebClient service (go to properties and make sure it starts automatically)

You will now be able to access your sharepoint via entering network path such as \sharepointhost\application\myawesomeapplication\ etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nop, I've started webClient service and made start automatically but nothing changed. It doesn't open from ribbon neither allow me to create a mapped folder. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just a note: in Server 2012, the "Desktop Experience" feature is inside a collapsed feature called "User Interfaces and Infrastructure". That feature appears to be fully installed, but you still need to install the Desktop Experience feature manually...

Answer (score 0):

- If you are trying to do this from the server, test it from a server which is **not** on the SharePoint farm (or better yet, a client machine). Ensure all of your testing is done from machines which are not on the farm.
- Do NOT enable the IIS WebDAV service, as SharePoint provides its own WebDAV service and the IIS one overrides it in the pipeline. Enabling this service is a sure path to breaking WebDAV.
- If you have SSL enabled, you may be in for a rough time getting it to work. Start by understanding how to use the 'net use' command, and the @SSL suffix.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure your webdav is installed as feature
- make the following registry fix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841215) :

  1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
  2. Add a new DWORD "BasicAuthLevel" and change this to "2"

Restart your machine (and make sure it is enabled in IIS)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that WebClient windows service is running in the server. This shall appear in client operating systems like Windows 7, windows 8 however, on the server operating systems like Windows Server 2008, it shall be installed by enabling the server feature "Desktop experience"  using Server Manager

Answer (score 0):

This issue nearly killed me. I found that I was using a 64 bit version of my browser and that is'nt supported. I changed over to the 32 bit and it works.